# Text loading based on selected ID using Ajax technique is not working

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to load the textbox data based on Selected ID using Ajax technique and update the row of the db through a small PHP program. Due to lack of knowledge I could not implement the Ajax part. Visiting the older posts could not help me.
I also want automatic increment of the id in Select Box, that is, if success $_POST['id']++ so that next id and the related text get loaded. My code as below:

```
        <?php
    function __autoload($class){
        require_once "classes/$class.php";
    }
    $id="";
    $Eng_Word="";
    $As_Meaning="";
    $Updatefield="";
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <div class ="container">
        <div class="card p-3 bg-secondary">
            <form action = "" method ="post">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group mb-5"
                    <label for="ID">SlNo</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="id" id="RowID" onchange = "DataLoad()">
                    <option value="">SlNo</option>
                    <?php
                        $getids = new GetData();
                        $rows = $getids->SelectIDs();
                        foreach($rows as $row)
                        {
                        echo '<option value=' .$row['id'] . '>' . $row['id']. '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                <?php

                    $getRow = new GetData();
                    $row = $getRow->selectRow(4);
                    ?>
                <?php
                $update = new GetData();
                //$update->dataUpdate();
                ?>
                <div class="form-group mb-5">
                        <label for="Eng_Word">English Word</label>
                        <input type="text"  value="<?php echo $row['Eng_Word'];?>" class="form- 
                        control">
                    </div>
                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="As_Meaning" id="AssameseMeaning" rows="6" ><? 
                php echo $row['As_Meaning'];?></textarea>.
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Newtextarea">New Meaning</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="Bn_Meaning" id="BengaliMeaning" placeholder = 
                "ইয়াত অৰ্থ লিখা হ'ব" rows="3"><?php echo $row['Bn_Meaning'];?></textarea>
              </div>
              <div>

              <input type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-right" name="update" 
              value="Save Now">
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function DataLoad() {
      var val = document.getElementById("RowID").value;
      self.location="update.php=" + val ;
    }
    </script>
    ?>
```

Comment: passed id as a querystring parameter like self.location="update.php?id=" + val;

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a key to your URL like so :

```
function DataLoad() {
      var val = document.getElementById("RowID").value;
      self.location="update.php?rowid=" + val ;
    }
```

And use it in your php like :

```
$_GET['rowid'];
```

Comment: Where I should use this $_GET['RowID'];?

Comment: Well where do you want to use your RowID value ?